# Collect tweets from a certain country

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, location

I am trying to run the Twitter Streaming API to collect only tweets from a certain country.

Trying to write long/lat coordinates as a filter gives the syntax error:

> positional argument follows keyword argument

I'm willing to use the geotag to filter by country or city, but have no idea what needs to be written into the code to do that.

A solution to stream only tweets from an approximate location would be great.

```
# Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Variables that contain the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = "put your keys here"
access_token_secret = "puts your keys here"
consumer_key = "puts your keys here"
consumer_secret = "puts your keys here"


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authentification and the connection to Twitter 
    Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
```

Comment: *You may want to regenerate your Twitter API keys hereafter.*

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Those are old keys though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the bounding box for your location in latitude and longitude. Something like this,

```
stream.filter(locations=[-74,40,-73,41])
```

Here is Twitter's [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#locations).

Comment: That is exactly what I tried that resulted in the  "positional argument follows keyword argument" error. Solutions?

Comment: I think you left it out of your code snippet so it's difficult to know what you did wrong. It's possible your coordinates are in the wrong order.